# Mac - how to delete all files NOT of a specific type

Tags: macos, unix

On Unix or Mac:

How do you delete all files NOT of a specific type. Or How to copy all files of a specific type with the containing folder.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is related to programming, do you wish to achieve this functionality in a program you are developing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), e.g. to delete all files which are not .txt files:

```
$ find . -type f -not -name \*.txt -exec rm -f {} \;
```

**WARNING:** use this kind of command with care as it's easy to delete a lot of files unintentionally. Do a "dry run" first if you're not confident, e.g. to preview the above command:

```
 $ find . -type f -not -name \*.txt -exec echo "Delete {}" \;
```